# is it correct to deploy mule application in j2ee server?

Tags: mule

We have a mule application. while deploying it into production we are converting into ear and doing that.

1) is it correct? or we have to use mule studio server?

since we are deploying as j2ee application we are defining data source in j2ee server and using it by spring code.

Due to this,  in local dev environment we are using different data-source look-up(defining data source using Apache basic data source), and in prod we are using different look-up(data source is already defined. so comment out dev code).

2) is this correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

1) It's up to you on how you want to deploy. a servlet container or the standalone Mule distribution are both feasible options both with their pros and cons. Here is a summary of each: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/32X/Deployment+Scenarios

2) Externalise the datasource configuration into to its own configuration file e.g 'datasources.xml' and only include it for the dev deployment using mule-deploy.properties for example